# Nginx not loading css/js/images in https - Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx 1.8.0. While opening the web pages in https the pages appear to be broken as the css/js/images don't load. I get this error "`Blocked loading mixed active content`"

This is my `nginx.conf`: https://github.com/adithyakhamithkar/ansible/blob/master/roles/nginx/templates/nginx.j2

This is my virtual host file:  https://github.com/adithyakhamithkar/ansible/blob/master/roles/nginx/templates/virtualhost_ssl.j2

Could some one please guide me how to fix this.

Comment: in ansible using `copy` instead of `template` for non-templated files avoids any chance of your file contents being munged on the fly.

Comment: I was reading a [similar issue](http://serverfault.com/questions/558511/nginx-not-serving-css-js?rq=1) the response code is 304 I see the same in my access logs.

Comment: I can use the `copy` for nginx.j2 but i'll have to use `template` for the virtual host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not fixable with nginx config

Consider the following html file:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img src="http://example.com/some/image.png">
    </body>
  </html>
```

If this html file is served over https - it will *always* generate a mixed content warning. Attempting to fix the subsequent request for `/some/image.png` will not work, the request is blocked by the browser and does not reach the server.

### Fix the html

The only effective solution is to fix the html source for the main request, such that it requests all assets from `https://` also i.e. change the html to this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img 
        src="/some/image.png" 
        alt="same domain and port as this html page please"
      />
    </body>
  </html>
```

Or this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img 
        src="https://example.com/some/image.png" 
        alt="explicit https" 
      />
    </body>
  </html>
```

In comments you've mentioned wordpress as an example; for a wordpress install the only thing required (in principle, in practice expect some messing about) is to [change the site url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) so that wordpress considers `https://example.com` to be the root url for the installation.

Answer (score 3):

Mixed Active Content is now blocked by default in Firefox 23 and above. Not sure about other browsers

> What is Mixed Content?
>
> When a user visits a page served over HTTP,
>   their connection is open for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle
>   (MITM) attacks. When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their
>   connection with the web server is authenticated and encrypted with SSL
>   and hence safeguarded from eavesdroppers and MITM attacks.
>
> However, if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can
>   be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served
>   over HTTPS. When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, we call that content
>   “mixed”. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially
>   encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over
>   HTTP. The Mixed Content Blocker blocks certain HTTP requests on HTTPS
>   pages.

Sounds like you are linking non-ssl static content. You should link your content like

```
<a href='//host.com/file.png>
```

If you need to link from another host.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a proxy to serve the non-ssl static content is ssl content?

Comment: I did read it [here](http://www.programering.com/a/MjM0MDMwATI.html)

Comment: Protocol relative urls are [now considered an anti-pattern](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) - the normal way to link to assets on the same host, with the same protocol is to simply not specify the host at all (i.e. `<link href="/css/screen.css"` ). @Adithya no, you cannot solve mixed content problems with a proxy (without changing the html to _not_ make http requests at least.).

Comment: Let me take an example of wordpress there would be a lot of code to be changed in that case what would you suggest me?

I was thinking about running 3 virtual hosts
1. running on port 80 - redirects to port 443
2. running on port 81 - wordpress on plan http
3. running on port 443 - proxy to port 81

Will this approach help?